# Doesn't the law of conservation of energy invalidate Ohm's law?

Tags: transformer, ac, resistance, ohms-law, energy

Imagine I have a power supply supplying a 12 amp AC current of 12 volts. The resistance of the circuit, consisting of only a copper wire and a resistor, is 1 ohm.

In this instance Ohm's law holds true:
$$V=I×R$$
$$12=12×1$$

This said if we use a 1:4 step-up transformer, to step the voltage up on another circuit consisting of copper wire and a 1-ohm resistor, our new voltage would be 48 and our new current would be 3.

The law of conservation of energy is followed as shown
$$I_1V_1=I_2V_2$$
$$12×12=48×3$$

However, Ohm's law is completely invalidated

$$48\neq3×1$$

The only way that Ohm's law and the law of conservation of energy agree is if resistance is no longer only dependent on factors such as geometry, material, and temperature.

Comment: You may find this helpful:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2xpb2vzJxA

Comment: If you have connected \$1\$ ohm at the secondary, then the current at the primary won't be  \$12A\$ .... because the impedance will be transformed to \$ 1/16 \$ ohms at the primary.

Comment: Step-up voltage but step-down current.  You cannot get something from nothing.

Comment: "*Ohm's law is completely invalidated*". When you find yourself thinking along those lines it is advisable to look for the error in your thinking.

Comment: Transformer also transforms impedance, as turns ratio squared. If the load is really still 1 ohm, you now have 48A at the output, and 48*4A or 12*16A at the input. Ohms law is satisfied, though your 12VAC source may not be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short anwer: No

Longer answer:
Your math is off. Off by much.

\$P = U * I\$

\$U = R * I\$

You got the first part right. You've got 12V and 12A on your 1 Ohm resistor. That 144W.

Not you put in a 1:4 transformer, making 48V.

This means, now you have \$I = U/R = 48V / 1 Ohm = 48A\$.

Power on the resistor is now **2304W**.

Now you have to know that a transformer that steps up the voltage by some factor at the same time draws more current on the primary side. This means instead of 12A your power supply now has to provide 16 times that current! So you need to provide 12V and 192A to your transformer (Which is: 2304W).

Conclusions:

- The law of energy conservations holds
- Transformers are not magical devices

Answer (score 5):

That's not how it works.

If you step up voltage to 48V, then that same 1 ohm resistor draws 48A current at 48V, not 3A.

The resistor will get 2.3 kilowatts, and you need 192 amps at 12V to provide it, and the 12A power supply can't provide it.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up the primary and secondary sides of the transformer.

Original circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLIHH6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Circuit with transformer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHhFWd.png)</sup>

What you did, is you took the first circuit, calculated the amount of current taken from the power supply, and then assumed the second circuit - a different circuit - used the same amount of current from the power supply. This isn't true, because the second circuit is a different circuit.

As you can see the transformer law and Ohm's law do both hold if the current from the power supply is 192A in the second circuit - which it is.

Answer (score 2):

You're incorrect to assume that a 1 ohm resistor to the secondary of your 1:4 transformer should draw the same power as a 1 ohm connected directly to the power supply. The correct assumption is that it would draw the same as a 1/16 ohm load \$(1/4^2)\$.

Proofing the maths, considering ideal 12V power supply:

- 1/16 \$\Omega\$ resistor, no transformer -> \$12\text{V}/(1/16) = 192 \text{A}\$ -> Power: \$12\text{V} \times 192 \text{A} = 2304 \text{W}\$
- 1 \$\Omega\$ resistor, after an ideal 1:4 step-up -> \$48\text{V}/(1) = 48\text{A}\$ -> Power: \$48\text{V} \times 48\text{A} = 2304 \text{W}\$

Try looking into "reflected impedance", to better understand where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't the law of conservation of energy invalidate Ohm's law?

Certainly not.

**Case 1:**

I = V/R = 12/1 = 12A

Output VA = 12 * 12 = 144

Ignoring transformer losses, Input VA = Output VA = 144.

**Case 2:**

I = V/R = 48/1 = 48A

Output VA = 48 * 48 = 2304

Ignoring transformer losses, Input VA = Output VA = 2304.

Considering both the cases, the rated VA of the transformer should be greater than 2304.